# GmailApp.sendEmail(...) creates a phishing warning

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-oauth, scopes, gmail-addons

when I use ...

```
GmailApp.sendEmail("test@gmail.com", "Testmail", "some text");
```

all sent emails are marked with a big red phishing warning (steal personal information) in Gmail.

Everything is fine with the following line (same without 'G') ...

```
MailApp.sendEmail("test@gmail.com", "Testmail", "some text");
```

I tried a lot to get rid of the warning. But even when I remove all modules the warning is still there. Well the warning is obviously a flag in my project which is automatically set/unset when I deploy a new version.

The only personal information I am asking for is the users email address.

```
Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
```

The needed scope to access the email address is granted by Google.

```
Scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

But this scope is not listed in my project scopes and in Stackdriver is a warning "no permission to access email address".

Any idea how I get rid of this phishing warning? To fix my scopes?

Thanks in advance
Klaus

Comment: You can manually specify your scopes by editing the manifest file. Make sure you include all required scopes, since adding the `oauthScopes` property will disable the normal automatic scope detection used by Apps Script. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests

Comment: Thx, I tried it, has no effect. 

To isolate the issue and reduce the impact of scope troubles I removed the getEmail() line. No changes.

Comment: During my tests I detected another behaviour.

1) When I send to an email address with domain (hosted on Gmail), only the first email contains the warning.
2) When I send to an @gmail.com email address, all emails are marked as phishing.

That was with the 'old' Gmail UI, with the new UI all emails are marked as phishing - caused by the different thread handling I guess)

For me, it looks like a problem in the Gmail phishing detection.

Regards